# Clear command is clearing too early C++

Tags: c++

I have a small problem with the clear command in C++. The Clear function is supposed to clear everything at the end of the program but it clears too early. Does anyone know how to solve that problem and let the program clear it as the complete end? I want that at the end the console is empty.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread> // sleep_for, sleep_until
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::this_thread; // sleep_for, sleep_until
using namespace std::chrono; 
int main() {
  cout<<"\nTest message?";
  sleep_for(nanoseconds(1500000000));
  system("clear");
  cout<<"\nThis message should be cleared";
  sleep_for(nanoseconds(5000000000));
  system("clear");
  }
```

Console output:

> This message should be cleared

Comment: `cout` is potentially buffered. Try flushing your outputs before sleeping by adding `<< std::flush`.

Comment: c++ also contains a suffix for creating nano seconds: you just type `num` + `ns` after, for example `5000000000ns` this converts it to miliseconds which is what `sleep_for` wants, other suffixes are `ms` for miliseconds , `us` for microseconds and `s, m, h` for seconds minutes and hours

Comment: As an aside, sleep_for doesn't require you to use nanoseconds. You could just as well use `sleep_for(1.5s)` and `sleep_for(5s)`.

Comment: What OS are you using that is accurate down to nanoseconds?  Some are accurate to milliseconds, but I haven't seen one that is accurate to nanoseconds.

Comment: Note:  `system("clear");` runs another program to clear the screen. This is pretty heavy, kinda like swatting a fly with a tank. Unfortunately there aren't many better ways to do when using IO streams. If it becomes a drag on performance, you'll need a dedicated console library like curses.

Answer (score 1):

standard cout in c++ is buffered.

this means that the text is held before it is sent to the screen, this helps with performance.

this is causing the clear to be called before the buffer is sent to the screen.

to fix this you need to manually flush the buffer by either putting `<< std::flush` or `<< std::endl` at the end of the `cout` statement

Comment: Actually just including `\n` is likely enough.  There may be no need for `std::endl`

Comment: `\n` does not flush the buffer, it only adds a new line

Comment: @blankettripod most terminals are line buffered, sending new line automatically does a flush, this is why `endl` isn't generally recommended, it ends up flushing twice

Comment: @AlanBirtles That's relying on implementation specific behavior. The problem with `std::cout` is when you use it after every line, even when more output is forthcoming. Using `std::cout` or `std::flush` is the correct thing to do when you want the text to be flushed, generally before a blocking operation that wouldn't otherwise flush (like using `cin`).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "*... before a blocking operation that wouldn't otherwise flush (like using `cin`)*" - `cin` and `cout` are `tie()`'d together by default, so a `cin` read will first flush any pending `cout` output. For example, to handle cases like `cout << "Input: "; cin >> value;` where the `cout` statement does not have a `'\n'` to flush the output buffer. People don't tend to like writing code like `cout << "Input: " << flush; cin >> value;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is why I used `cin` as an example of a blocking operation that flushes. I guess my wording is ambiguous, sorry.